# How to access class members (injected services in this case) in a decorator in typescript

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I've written a simple `PersonService` that look as follows:

```
@Injectable()
export class PersonsService {

    constructor(
        private httpService: HttpService,
        private cacheService: CacheService,
    ) {}

    public async getPersonWithCache(id: number): Promise<Person> {
        if (await this.cacheService.hasKey(id)) {
            console.log('Hitting the cache...');
            return this.cacheService.getPerson(id);
        } else {
            const person = await this.httpService.get(`http://localhost:3000/persons/${id}`)
            .pipe(map((rawPerson: AxiosResponse<IPersonRawResponse>) => new Person().deserialize(rawPerson.data)))
            .toPromise();

            this.cacheService.setPerson(id, person);

            return person;
        }
    }

    public async getPerson(id: number): Promise<Person> {
        return this.httpService.get(`http://localhost:3000/persons/${id}`)
        .pipe(map((rawPerson: AxiosResponse<IPersonRawResponse>) => new Person().deserialize(rawPerson.data)))
        .toPromise();
    }
```

What I would like to do is to use `Cacheable` custom decorator on the `getPerson` function.

I've started writing it. not this is what it looks like:

```
export function Cacheable() {
    // tslint:disable-next-line: only-arrow-functions
    return function(target: Object, key: string | symbol, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        const original = descriptor.value;
        // tslint:disable-next-line: only-arrow-functions
        descriptor.value = function(... args: any[]) {
            return original.apply(this, args);
        };
    };
}
```

So it does not do much. I was just trying to figure out how to access the `cacheService` inside that function, I've never worked with decorators in typescript before and it's not clear from the docs.

I would appreciate it immensely if someone would explain to me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just adding it as a parameter to the `@Cachable` decorator factory?

E.g.

`@Cachable(cacheService)`

Answer (score 0):

You can access it from the function you decorate as `this.cacheService`:

```
descriptor.value = function (this: { cacheService: CacheService }, ...args: any[]) {
  console.log(this.cacheService);
  return original.apply(this, args);
};
```